# Log in using Google Apps account using Janrain Exchange (http://www.janrain.com)

Tags: google-apps, janrain

I tried logging in using my google app account (user@my-domain.com) but it says no such user (or something to that effect).

According to http://www.janrain.com/solutions/supported-networks/google-api,

Janrain Exchange can support google app accounts, but how exactly do i do it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I've implemented Janrain Exchange last day, and yes, it works fine with Google accounts, but not with app-account.

To login to app accounts you have to access is from a specific page, not the usual Gmail address, for example, so Janrain should do the same, maybe providing a second button "Google Apps" beside "Google"